# Windows Boot Manager still present even after removing Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, bootloader

I had originally installed Windows 10 on my PC on SSD. Then I decided to dual boot Ubuntu alongside but on HDD. The grub was installed on the HDD, hence to see the GRUB menu, I had to select HDD (named as Ubuntu in BIOS, and SSD was named Windows Boot Manager) in the boot priority.

Now I installed Ubuntu on SSD and formatted the SSD while installing. I was expecting to get rid of Windows. But in the BIOS, the SSD is still named as Windows Boot Manager instead of Ubuntu, and when SSD is selected first in boot priority, it opens recovery mode. I see GRUB only when I HDD is placed first in the boot priority.

So, how do I remove the Windows Boot Manager from SSD, and make It Ubuntu. So that when I select SSD first in Boot priority, it directly boots into Ubuntu without opening the grub.

Boot priority:

[image: Boot priority]

Windows Error Recovery Mode:

[image: Windows Error Recovery Mode]

Grub boot menu:

[image: Grub boot menu]

The output of `sudo os-prober` :

```
/dev/sdb2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/sdb3:Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04):Ubuntu:linux
/dev/sdb4:Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS (20.04):Pop:linux
```

Here the Ubuntu on the `sdb3` disk is the Ubuntu installed earlier, the newer Ubuntu on SSD is not shown.

I deleted the `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/`, now the `Windows Boot Manager` has been removed, but the SSD is not available to boot into directly.

New boot priority options:

[image: New boot priority options]

I wanted to get rid of the Windows Boot Manager, which I did by removing the`/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/` folder.

When I was using Windows, I could select SSD or HDD the first option in boot priority. When I selected SSD which had Windows 10 installed on it, I would boot directly to the Windows, without any GRUB prompt. But when I selected the HDD, I would get the GRUB prompt with windows, Ubuntu and Pop!_OS as the options.

Now I want to achieve similar results, just that instead of Windows, I want to use Ubuntu on the SSD. So that when SSD is selected first in the boot priority, it would boot into Ubuntu on the SSD without any GRUB prompt, but when I select the HDD first in the boot priority, I would get the GRUB prompt, to select the Ubuntu (from SSD), Ubuntu (from HDD) or Pop!_OS.

Now the problem is that I cannot see the SSD in the BIOS boot priority as seen in the 4th screen photo. Earlier I could select SSD or HDD like in the 1st screen photo. Windows Boot Manager being the SSD and the other OS being the HDD.

Comment: Have you the folder ```/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/``` in your SSD ? If yes , you can delete it.I'm not 100% sure but I think that would be enough.

Comment: It sounds like you have left over mess from your previous installations.  You're booting to the HDD, not your new Ubuntu install.  Do you intend to have only Ubuntu?  If so, you should format your hard drives prior to the installation.  At least delete all of the partitions for operating systems that you are getting rid of. The installer won't clean these up for you.

Comment: @Nmath I wish to keep the OS' which are installed on the HDD. While installing the Newer Ubuntu I did for the SSD, on which Windows was earlier installed. I think the bootloader was on HDD, and the Windows Boot loader was still on the HDD efi partition.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I deleted that folder, but now the SSD is not visible in the boot priority in the BIOS mode.

Comment: Is there any folder in your ```/boot/efi/EFI``` other than **BOOT** ? If not , you have to install grub2.Try ```sudo grub-install your_ssd_device ```

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I think I solved it. The reason SSD is not present in Boot Priority is that it does not have any EFI partition. This is necessary for a disk to be able to boot with it. While installation I mounted the `/` to the SSD and the efi was still the efi partition in the HDD, hence to use SSD as boot disk, I need to have an EFI partition, and install Ubuntu with that SSD as the mount point for the EFI

Comment: You should have one (1) EFI partition for your entire system. If you already have an EFI partition, don't make another one...

Comment: @Nmath I read one online article. It said to make a new EFI partition on the SSD and then delete the old EFI partition on HDD. I did not want to screw my laptop, hence I did not try that. Would that method work, or would it leave my laptop unbootable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Parsa Mousavi in comments.

"Have you the folder /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/ in your SSD? If yes, you can delete it. I'm not 100% sure but I think that would be enough"

And yeah this did work.